# Flowplayer video keeps playing in background hidden span

Tags: javascript, php, flowplayer, video-player

Here its the index file (javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    player("video-1.mov","player1");
    player("video-2.mov","player2");
    player("video-3.mov","player3");
});

function player(video,id) {
    flowplayer(id, "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.14.swf", {
        playlist: [video],
        clip:  {
              autoPlay: true,
              autoBuffering: true
        }
    });
}

function goto_next(current,page)
{
    $('#'+current).hide();
    $('#'+page).show();
    flowplayer.unload();
}
```

This is the index file

```
<span id="1" class="step">
    <div class="player formplayer" id="player1"></div>
</span>
<span id="2" class="step" style="display:none;">
    <div class="player formplayer" id="player2"></div>
</span>
<span id="3" class="step" style="display:none;">
    <div class="player formplayer" id="player3"></div>
</span>
```

When I click on next button it will call goto_next with two different id's to show/hide.
But, the video of previous span is keep playing in background.
**How to stop all other videos and play the current video only?**

P.S.: It is working fine on windows: chrome, firefox.

But having problem with firefox on mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stop the players with the stop() function of the javascript api (http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html)

```
function goto_next(current,page)
{
    flowplayer(0).stop();
    flowplayer(1).stop();
    flowplayer(2).stop();
    $('#'+current).hide();
    $('#'+page).show();
    flowplayer.unload();
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked and I've also started video for the next page